# ORA-01722 Error when Returning Identity Column into variable

Tags: oracle19c

I have the table below, and I am inserting a record into it. For some reason, the `RETURNING [column_name] INTO [variable]` is throwing an `ORA-01722: invalid number` error. I've looked at other similar issues on stack overflow and elsewhere and only thing I found is someone was using a variable for the `[column_name]` that needed an extra step, but i'm using the `[column_name]` explicitly.

```
TABLE:
    catalog_year
      catalog_year_id    number       (pk, identity column)
      catalog_year       varchar2(10)
      catalog_status_id  number 

declare
  l_new_calendar_year_id  number;

begin
    insert into catalog_year
      (catalog_year, catalog_status_id)
    values
      ('2022-2023', 5)
    returning catalog_year_id into l_new_calendar_year_id;
end;
```

Comment: [Seems to work OK](https://dbfiddle.uk/tzzkeA8R). Are you sure it's the returning clause - the error doesn't occur is you remove that? Is there a trigger on the table that might be throwing the error? The full error message/stack would tell you, if so.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. You were right. My lines were off by 2 and was debugging the wrong thing. Appreciate the 'fresh' par of eyes. Been at this for over 12 hours. Think I need to step away and rest a bit. Feel free to modify comment as answer if you want me to mark as answer. Thx again.